# How large can be a model to be deployed on android application with pytorch mobile?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, pytorch

I have a model with the size of 1.3 GB and I am trying to deploy it into an android application (java|kotlin) with pytorch mobile. However, model can not be loaded in android studio. Everything as it should be. I quantized the model and reduced the size to 800 mb but still does not work. I am wondering how much should a model be? Is there any way to increase android application variable sizes.